# Java: Regular expression for the input field only numbers and commas + space characters

Tags: java, regex

There is a field that is filled with numbers or groups of numbers.

After the comma must be a space!

The symbol "`,`" and the space cannot be the beginning and `/` or at the end of the field

```
^[\d+]{1,}([,]{1}[\s]{1}).*[\d+]$ 
- this does not work. please help to write a regular expression according to the described condition.
```

example

```
1 - ok!
2, 3 - ok!
6, 7, 4 -ok!
,5 - bad!
5 6 0 - bad!
4,5 - bad!
```

Comment: do you have a question?

Comment: And could you give an example value of this mysterious "field"? Your description of the input data is quite fuzzy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a repeating group with a space (or `\s`) prepended.

In your pattern you could remove the `.*` and match the last `\d+` inside the group. Then repeat the group 0+ times.

It would look like `^[\d]{1,}([,]{1}[\s]{1}[\d]+)*$`

Note that you don't have to put the `\d+` between square brackets or else the `+` would be matched literally and the quantifier `{1}` could be omitted:

```
^\d+(?:, \d+)*$
```

In Java

```
String regex = "^\\d+(?:, \\d+)*$";
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uSKvME/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/gCtv9E)